# arraymap is better than sparse array to memorise some data catched from a JSON file?

Tags: android, arrays

I had wrote a code which use a parse to catch some data from a JSON file but i don't know what kind of structure is better between the sparse array or the array map for memorise these data ?

I had used a array map but I don't know if it's too wasted on so little data data.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressDialog pd;
private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public ArrayMap<Integer, ValoriDiSueg> ArrayDati = new ArrayMap<>();



Button buttonProg;
TextView textViewProg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonProg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    textViewProg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    buttonProg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new JsonCLASS().execute("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22");
        }
    });

}

private class JsonCLASS extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Please wait");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here u ll get whole response...... :-)

            }

            return buffer.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The parse of these data

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray Arr = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("weather"));
            for (int i = 0; i < Arr.length(); i++){

                JSONObject jsonPart = Arr.getJSONObject(i);


                 ArrayDati.put(i,new ValoriDiSueg( jsonPart.getString("main"), jsonPart.getString("description")));
                //ArrayDati.put(i,new ValoriDiSueg("description : "+ jsonPart.getString("description")));
                textViewProg.setText(textViewProg.getText()+"main : "+ ArrayDati.get(i).Main +"\n"+textViewProg.getText()+"description : "+ ArrayDati.get(i).Description );

            }

        } catch (Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }


    }


}
}
```

And I created a class:

```
public class ValoriDiSueg {

 String Main;
 String Description;


 public ValoriDiSueg(String main, String description) {
     this.Main  = main;
     this.Description = description;
 }

 }
```

any suggestions??

Comment: So what is the question?  Are you just looking for advice--whether to use a `SparseArray` or a `ArrayMap`?

Comment: Just read the documentation [SparseArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray) and [ArrayMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/collection/ArrayMap)

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), and  [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561)

Comment: Oh ok thanks,  any suggestions for the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple:

- If your key is int or long, you should use SparseArray, SparseLongArray as it will not boxing/un-boxing the key value when operates. Also, it provides similar classes for int/long values as long as the key is int/long.
- If you key is not int nor long, such as an object or String, you should use ArrayMap instead as it will handle the conflicts of key hashes.

There are no much performance and memory usage difference between these two class as they are all requires O(log n) to search and O(n) to insert/delete (in most cases).